# Returning the value of a cell corresponding to the 5 latest dates

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, vlookup, lookup

So for a football team I use google spreadsheets to plan matches ahead and also store our results. Now for a overview or summary spreadsheet I'm trying to get it to show the form of the team based on the latest 5 played matches. So the list of unplayed and played matches looks like this:

```
Type|Date|Opponent|Location|Kick off|Result|W/D/L
```

So whenever a match has been played I complete the row of that specific match by filling in the result with whatever score was achieved (e.g. 2-1,1-1 etc.) and either a W D or L in the final column based on the result. So to show the form of the team in last 5 matches I thought I could just use an easy vlookup to return the corresponding W D or L, so it would eventually show a something like W W D L W. What I tried was this:

```
=(Vlookup(LARGE datecolumn;1);range;7;TRUE)
=(Vlookup(LARGE datecolumn;2);range;7;TRUE)
=(Vlookup(LARGE datecolumn;3);range;7;TRUE)
=(Vlookup(LARGE datecolumn;4);range;7;TRUE)
=(Vlookup(LARGE datecolumn;5);range;7;TRUE)
```

But this didn't work as unplayed matches are also in the list, so it just returns empty cells. So I'm looking for a way to make it return the value corresponding to the latest date and that isn't an empty cell. When doing my own search around on the subject for multi criteria look ups I can find methods to get either the first or last non empty value, but no way to get it for the last five. But because the exact workings and logic behind the first or last non empty value methods go beyond my knowledge, so I couldn't figure out a way to modify or combine them with other functions to make them do what I want. So I was hoping someone here could show me the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     =CONCATENATE(QUERY(B1:H17,"Select H where H is not null order by  C desc limit 5",0))
```

You can use query like it is given above. Here B1:H17 will be the whole table. H will be the final column with WDL  and C will be the date column.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works. But I probably didn't specify this clearly, I want every individual W, D or L to be in a separate cell. Could that be done with a similar method as you provided above?

Comment: @Phil Remove the concatenate from the formula